# Postgres on the command line with external editor not running query

Tags: postgresql, command-line, editor, sublimetext2

When I run `\e` on the command line while logged into the `psql` command line tool, my default editor, sublime text, duitifully opens. However, when I type in a query like this:

```
create table tutorials (
  tutorial_id serial primary key,
  title text,

  author_id integer references authors(author_id)

);
```

Then hit save and exit, nothing happens! My query is not run. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: After having left the editor you are in the psql shell again. enter `\g` to execute te query in the buffer (or `\e` to edit again ;-)

Comment: Just tried that - did not work

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem until I added the -w switch to export EDITOR.

From http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html:

- To use Sublime Text as the editor for many commands that prompt for
  input, set your EDITOR environment variable:
- **export EDITOR='subl -w'**
- Specifying -w will cause the subl command to not exit until the file
  is closed.

Comment: after using `export EDITOR='subl -w'` in my bash file, psql could no longer work with sublime

Comment: I wish I could be more helpful.  What happens when you give command /e?  Before I solved the sublime problem, I could set nano as the editor and get the behavior I wanted.  Can you get any editor to work for executing psql commands?

Answer (score 2):

After the editor exits, type `\p` to see what the editor put back into the query buffer.

Comment: Just did that - editor shows nothing - just a big blank multiline space. So does that mean the buffer is broken? How do I fix this?

Comment: That means your editor isn't saving anything back to where it should.

Comment: I had a similar problem on my Mac and noticed that my client was apparently defaulting to vi.  Setting EDITOR=vim worked for me, however.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this while experiencing a similar problem, nothing here helped. Eventually tried it with another editor (nano) which seemed to fix it. From there, I nuked my vimrc and added everything back. Strangely enough, that seemed to fix it. Thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41472024/postgres-external-editor-does-not-execute-query-on-savequit).

Answer (score 0):

After explicitly setting the PSQL_EDITOR variable it works on macOS Sierra/vim 8/psql 9.4.5

```sh
export PSQL_EDITOR="vim"
```

If you want to make the setting persistent add it to the `~/.profile`

*PS:
Although psql seemed to open vim before setting PSQL_EDITOR I was experiencing the same problem as the OP.*