# Postgres external editor does not execute query on savequit

Tags: postgresql, vim

This is driving me slightly insane. I'm trying to edit a query using `\e` in postgres, but upon savequitting `:wq` nothing happens.
Running `\p`, which shows what the editor saved, just comes up with a blank line, or whatever I ran most recently in the cli. It seems likethe editor is not persisting whatsoever.

I'm using vim as my default editor, and I'm on psql version 9.5.4. Operating system is OSX and I'm using iterm2. The only similar problem I could find online was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071309/postgres-on-the-command-line-with-external-editor-not-running-query), and no advice there seemed to help.

All ideas are welcomed!

EDIT: Found the problem. It was something to do with my vim -- things worked when I set my editor to Pico, so I nuked my vimrc and slowly readded things. Oddly, when everything was up again it continued to work. So check if it works with another editor!

Comment: Didn't you forget the final semicolon? It works perfectly on my server and I also use PostGreSQL 9.5.4 with vim.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the problem -- I think something deeper is going on. When I'm editing the file, I can see the temp file and it appears to be being updated correctly. However when I save it, it seems like it's not persisting to psql for some reason

Comment: Perhaps related to the `backupcopy` setting? Vim writes files in a somewhat unusual way, also see [this answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/138/51).

Comment: @PeterDolan I don't suppose you can post your previous `.vimrc`?
I'm seeing this exact problem and I use [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why exactly but it looks like the `$EDITOR` environment variable needs to be set for this to work.

Start psql like this:

```
EDITOR=vim psql ...
```

Or longer term, add

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

to your `.bashrc` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that this occurs when using the **Janus vim distribution**, and have [created an issue over there](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/689) to track it. Once resolved over there it'll give us a clue and I can give a specific answer here.

In the interim add the following to your `~/.profile` as a workaround:

```
export PSQL_EDITOR="vim -u NONE"
```

You will lose Janus functionality (and anything else in your `.vimrc.before` and `.after`, but it will let you use vim.

---

See:

- [`vim -u`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-u) switch.
- [`PSQL_EDITOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-ENVIRONMENT) env var.